# What's the difference between “问一下”，“查询”， “询问”？

Tags: word-choice, usage

In the context of phone conversations with vendors I often default to either:

- 我想问一下…
- 请问…

I'm looking for a possibly more appropriate way to address someone in this context. Would it be appropriate to say any of the following?

- 我想查询您…
- 我想询问您…

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Would it be appropriate to say any of the following?
>
> 我想查询您…

This usage is wrong. `查询` should be followed by the object being asked for, not the person who is being asked. The correct usages are

- `我想查询[sth]。`
- `我想向[sb]查询[sth]。`

Example:

- 我想（向您）查询从北京到上海的机票价格。

> 我想询问您…

This one is correct. `询问` can be used in three ways:

- `我想询问[sth]`
- `我想询问[sb][sth]`
- `我想向[sb]询问[sth]`

Example:

- 我想询问从北京到上海的机票价格。
- 我想询问您从北京到上海的机票价格。
- 我想向您询问从北京到上海的机票价格。

Both of them are formal but never too formal to use in daily conversations; I use them from time to time when talking to a service personnel, especially when over the phone.